# How to parse api request using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am learning how to use Yelp API from [this yelp blog](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2014/04/more-yelp-in-your-ruby.html) and [yelp github](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby) on Rails. I was able to connect to Yelp service and got a response back, but I don't know what to do with the response that I got back.

Here is what I did, on `Rails Console`:

```
2.2.2 :057 >   response = client.search('los angeles', {limit: 2})
=> #<Yelp::Response::Search:0x007fff32edc2c0 @region=#<Yelp::Response::Model::Region:0x007fff35ddf6d0 @span=#<Yelp::Response::Model::RegionSpan:0x007fff35ddf450 @latitude_delta=0.04455494999999132, @longitude_delta=0.02209966000000918>, @center=#<Yelp::Response::Model::RegionCenter:0x007fff35ddf5e0 @latitude=34.08390635, @longitude=-118.3184503>>,...
```

1. What kind of format is that? [this article](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby#responses) says that when I make API call to Yelp, it gives ruby object, but I am not sure what data type `#<Yelp::Response...` is. I guess I was expecting a ruby array/ json format return, like stated in the article:
   `

   ### search

   response = client.search('San Francisco')

   response.businesses

   ## [< Business 1>, < Business 2 >, ...]

   response.businesses[0].name

   ## "Kim Makoi, DC"

   response.businesses[0].rating

   ## 5.0
2. If I want to select a specific information, say `display_address`, or `neighborhood` from the return API, how can I do that? (Here is the end part of the same API request):

   `...@display_address=["6353 Yucca St", "Hollywood", "Los Angeles, CA 90028"], @geo_accuracy=8.0, @postal_code="90028", @country_code="US", @address=["6353 Yucca St"], @coordinate=#<Yelp::Response::Model::Coordinate:0x007fff35ddf7e8 @latitude=34.10413, @longitude=-118.32834>, @state_code="CA", @neighborhoods=["Hollywood"]>, @deals=nil, @gift_certificates=nil, @reviews=nil>]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
If you were to call the API directly (say, from cURL), you'd get JSON back.

You're using the Yelp gem, though, so it's helpfully converting that JSON into a ruby object for you. If you're interested in the construction of the object, you can take a look at how the gem is doing the conversion on [GitHub](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby/tree/develop/lib/yelp/responses).

You should be able to interact with that response just like the article states, i.e. `results.businesses` should give you an array of businesses found.

2. More concretely, it looks like you can do something like:

`results.businesses[0].display_address` to get the display address for the first business found
`results.businesses[0].neighborhoods` is an array of all neighborhoods associated with that same business.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I didn't realize that I need to do dot notation `businesses` to "convert" it to array format. I was able to run `result.businesses[0].location.display_address` and got the address. Thanks for the help!